# What's wrong in my code? It fails just 2 of the test cases without showing any error

Tags: javascript

I have started learning programming on my own just a few months back. So pardon me if my question sounds a bit silly.

One of the challenges on freeCodeCamp needs to define a function that takes an array with 2 values as an input and the function should return the LCM of all the numbers within that range inclusive of those 2 numbers.

My code below passes the tests number 1,2,3,6 given in the exercise. but somehow fails for the tests 4 & 5. Also freeCodeCamp is not showing any error! So I am unable to figure out what am I doing wrong in the below code.

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  let allNum = [];

  for (let i = Math.min(...arr); i <= Math.max(...arr); i++) {
    allNum.push(i);
  }

  function findFactors(x) {
    let allFactors = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
      if (x % i == 0) {
        allFactors.push(i);
      }
    }
    return allFactors;
  }

  function findGCF(a,b) {
    return findFactors(a).filter(item => findFactors(b).includes(item)).reduce((p,q) => p*q);        
  }

  return allNum.reduce((a,b) => ((a*b)/findGCF(a,b)));
}
```

The tests given in the exercise are as follows. My code passes 1,2,3 & 6 but fails 4 & 5.

```
smallestCommons([1, 5]) should return a number.
smallestCommons([1, 5]) should return 60.
smallestCommons([5, 1]) should return 60.
smallestCommons([2, 10]) should return 2520.
smallestCommons([1, 13]) should return 360360.
smallestCommons([23, 18]) should return 6056820.
```

```js
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  let allNum = [];

  for (let i = Math.min(...arr); i <= Math.max(...arr); i++) {
    allNum.push(i);
  }

  function findFactors(x) {
    let allFactors = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
      if (x % i == 0) {
        allFactors.push(i);
      }
    }
    return allFactors;
  }

  function findGCF(a,b) {
    return findFactors(a).filter(item => findFactors(b).includes(item)).reduce((p,q) => p*q);        
  }

  return allNum.reduce((a,b) => ((a*b)/findGCF(a,b)));
}

console.log(smallestCommons([1, 5])); // should return a number.
console.log(smallestCommons([1, 5])); // should return 60.
console.log(smallestCommons([5, 1])); // should return 60.
console.log(smallestCommons([2, 10])); // should return 2520.
console.log(smallestCommons([1, 13])); // should return 360360.
console.log(smallestCommons([23, 18])); // should return 6056820.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `findGCF` function is off. To find the GCF of two numbers, you should find the largest factor which evenly divides both. Eg

`findGCF(60, 6)`

should be 6. (But yours returns 36)

```js
function findFactors(x) {
  // console.log(x);
  let allFactors = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
    if (x % i === 0) {
      allFactors.push(i);
    }
  }
  return allFactors;
}

function findGCF(a, b) {
  const bFac = findFactors(b);
  return findFactors(a)
    .filter(item => bFac.includes(item))
    .reduce((p, q) => p * q);
}

console.log(findGCF(60, 6)); // should be 6
```

To reduce the computational complexity *and* fix it at the same time, make a Set of one of the factor collections, then iterate over an array of the other factor collections, *starting from the largest factor and working your way downwards*, and `.find` the first factor which is contained in the Set (it may end up being 1):

```
function findGCF(a, b) {
  const bFacSet = new Set(findFactors(b));
  return findFactors(a)
    .reverse()
    .find(item => bFacSet.has(item));
}
```

Fix that, and your `smallestCommons` function works as desired:

```js
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  const allNum = [];

  for (let i = Math.min(...arr); i <= Math.max(...arr); i++) {
    allNum.push(i);
  }

  function findFactors(x) {
    const allFactors = [];
    for (let i = x; i >= 1; i--) {
      if (x % i === 0) {
        allFactors.push(i);
      }
    }
    return allFactors;
  }

  function findGCF(a, b) {
    const bFacSet = new Set(findFactors(b));
    return findFactors(a)
      .find(item => bFacSet.has(item));
  }

  return allNum.reduce((a,b) => ((a*b)/findGCF(a,b)));
}
console.log(smallestCommons([2, 10])) // should return 2520.
console.log(smallestCommons([1, 13])) // should return 360360.
```